# Redirect without loading the route component in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, typescript

I've defined a resolver for my signup route:

```
import {IsLoggedin} from './share/is-loggedin.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'signup', resolve: [IsLoggedin], component: SignupComponent}
]
```

In the resolver I'm redirecting to a certain page if the user is logged in:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerState: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.authService.isUserAuthenticated()
               .subscribe(
                   (res: any) => {
                       if (res === true) {
                           this.router.navigate(['/main-board']);
                       }
                   }
               );
}
```

But, angular loads the `SignupComponent` anyway before redirecting to the **main-board** page.

**Note:** I've tried with `CanActivate` guard, but it still can't redirect without loading the componenet as  `isUserAuthenticated()` method returns a `Observable` and doesn't work synchronized way.

I really want to know whether it is possible in angular to redirect to the **main-board** page without loading the `SignupComponent`.

Can it be done smoothly in angular 2/4 ?

I would really appreciate if someone help me.

Comment: Consider using guards for your case. Maybe a CanActivate guard ? https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: `CanActivate` guard still it can't redirect without loading the componenet as  `isUserAuthenticated()` method returns a `Observable` and doesn't work synchronized way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) guard is used instead of [Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) then the redirection will be smooth. Then it won't load the route component `SignupComponent` before the redirection:

```
import {IsLoggedin} from './share/is-loggedin.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'signup', canActivate: [IsLoggedin], component: SignupComponent}
]
```

The the is-loggedin.service.ts :

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerState: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    /* this.authService.isUserAuthenticated() return an http Observable */
    return this.authService.isUserAuthenticated()
               .map((res: any) => {
                       if (res === true) {
                           this.router.navigate(['/main-board']);
                           return false;
                       }
                       return true;
                   }
               );
}
```